# sftp How to get stat attributes?

Tags: sftp

Is it possible to do `stat` via `sftp` cli tool? For example [Python's SFTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205731/how-to-check-a-remote-path-is-a-file-or-a-directory) has this feature, but I didn't find it in `sftp` cli tool. I need to get SFTP attributes to work with in script.

Answer (score 3):

The `sftp` tool in OpenSSH does not have `stat` command (otherwise it would be listed in the manual page as supported commands). But the protocol itself is using `stat` to retrieve the information about remote files (for `ls` mostly). So to the answer:

- No, there is no possibility to get raw `stat` data from `sftp` cli (only what you can get from `ls`, `ls -l` and so)
- At best, you should try to write a script in python

Comment: I have the same problem A pity the Linux CLI story for SFTP is so poor I cannot do even a simple stat. Here I come Python script.